# Declare Global Variable in zeppelin notebook using mongodb interprter?

Tags: mongodb, apache-zeppelin

Guys, I'm working with Zeppelin I want to create a notebook using MongoDB interpreter, angular and spark when I use MongoDB interpreter for example:

```
    %mongodb
    total=db.smoething.find().count()
    z.put("total",total)
```

$it gives me

```
    [js] ReferenceError: z is not defined
```

any help please?

Comment: zeppelin context (z variables is available in only few interpreters).
can you try print("%spark z.put('total', "+total+")")

Comment: hello @SaravananElumalai it gives " error: not found: value total"